# Add minutes to PHP Datetime to calculate start/end of event

Tags: php, dateinterval

I would like to calculate with PHP the start and end datetime of an event. I get the start of this event and the duration to add to get the end. So I tried the following code:

```
$startTime = $this->getStartTime();
$endTime = $this->getStartTime();

$endTime->add(new DateInterval('PT75M'));
```

in this example I add 75 minutes to the start time and I calculate the end of the event. It works, however it edits also the start time. I read in the PHP docs that the ADD method edits the object which is called on but I don't understand how it could edit the startEdit variable. I don't use reference in any of the methods that I wrote in the example, neither in the getStartTime function

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to create a new DateTime instance for that or you will be editing your original reference to your start date DateTime object. Try something like this:

```
$endTime = clone $startTime;
$endTime->add(new DateInterval('PT75M'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to change `getStartTime()` method's return type, I highly recommend changing it from `\DateTime` to `\DateTimeImmutable`.

Then the code will go as follows:

```
$endTime = $startTime->add(new DateInterval('PT75M'));
```

More examples and advantages of this approach [are described pretty well in this Nikola Poša's blog article](https://www.nikolaposa.in.rs/blog/2019/07/01/stop-using-datetime/).

Comment: You should explain your opening assertion. Leaving it to external links isn't ideal on SO. (I can't see that site on my network.) See [answer].